# addClass with the full match of id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried to addClass with the full match of id in jquery, for some reason it's addClass for any partially matched id as well.

Example:
I have the following html code:

```
<span>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1">0</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-1">1</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-2">2</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-3">3</e>
</span>
```

I have the following jquery code to add the class:

```
$("e[id*=PID-1]").addClass("foundYou");
```

For some reason, it's add Class for all 4 ids that start with PID-1

Does anyone how's going wrong with my code?

Comment: Why dont you do ->  `$('#PID-1').addClass("foundYou");`

Comment: it means that it will select all that contains the `PID-1` string which it did

Comment: [select *](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

`

Answer (score 3):

Please try below line for add class, based on full match Id.

```
$("#PID-1").addClass("foundYou");
```

**foundYou** Class add in **PID-1** id

Answer (score 1):

`$("e[id*=PID-1]").addClass("foundYou");` will give you all the matching elements with id selector. If you want to target any specific one, then you have to get the element by array like below:

```js
$($("e[id*=PID-1]")[0]).addClass("foundYou");
```

```css
.foundYou{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1">0</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-1">1</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-2">2</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-3">3</e>
</span>
```

**Alternatively** as I mentioned with my comment, easiest way to match element with id is using selector to get element:

```
$("#PID-1").addClass("foundYou");
```

Comment: The latter solution is best. Or even just `id=`; it's the asterisk that makes it loose.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wild card `*` to match id.

What `id*=PID-1` mean?

This will select `PID-1` anywhere in the id.Your all id have `PID-1` so it's add class for all.

You can use `:first` selector like below to add class in your first wild card match.

```js
$("e[id*=PID-1]:first").addClass("foundYou");
```

```css
.foundYou {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1">0</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-1">1</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-2">2</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-3">3</e>
</span>
```

Alternative you can use `filter` function with RegEx to match exact id:

```js
$('e')
  .filter(function() {
    return this.id.match(/^PID-1$/);
  })
  .addClass("foundYou");
```

```css
.foundYou {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-1">1</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-2">2</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1-3">3</e>
  <e class="test" id="PID-1">0</e>
</span>
```

Comment: Good explanation, but there are a couple ways to narrow it down and `:first` only works here because of current HTML order, not because it's an exact match.

Comment: Thanks. Solution as per  your comment is in  alternative section.